# Fn+f2 will not enable wifi

Tags: wireless

I have a dell inspiron 640m and i have looked at many other answers i have tried the rfkill and it doesn't display anything i have tried looking at answers for three days and nothing has worked. How can i activate the fn+f2 key? I have been in chat rooms and people have tried to help as well but i have not received a working answer please try and help! I have tried the mod approach as well and it has not come up with anything that has helped me either.

Comment: Have you contacted Dell or even looked at the Dell website?

Comment: May we know your wireless card details? lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
If this doesnt fix it try the steps from this link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1778094&highlight=dell-laptop

Comment: The sudo ifconfig does not work and neither does the information on the link that you gave me.

My Wireless card is broadcom 4311 802.11 g/b

Comment: Which driver is being used? lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43